# How to correctly have binary logs stored.....Mysql/Maria

Tags: mariadb, logs, backup, xtrabackup

So I'm taking a full backup at 12AM each day. 
At 2,4,6,8,10etc etc I'm taking incrementals.

Using Mariadb and maraibackup...

At each point I want to flush and purge the logs so I don't have to take the extra parts with me. at 11:59:59 I want to put all the incremental backups back into the main one and store it offsite with the approprriate binary logs... how can I do this?

-R.

Comment: I think you have to take a new full and toss the incrementals.

Comment: @RickJames you can merge down the incrementals..iinto the full but my question is after the last incremental there will be some time beforre the new fulll..... the binary logs should have the rollforward at that poiont...